# Initializing shared_ptr<unit8_t> data member

Tags: c++

I've been having an issue initializing a private data member that is a shared_ptr type.

**Header:**

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> data_;

  public:
    uint8_t data();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
  this->data_((uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)), free);
}
```

**Error:**

> error: type 'shared_ptr' does not provide a call operator

However, this does work:

> std::shared_ptr data((uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)),
>   free);

Of course, that doesn't provide the desired result.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` with `shared_ptr`. Use `new`.

Comment: First you need to do an assignment or initialize it in the ctor initializer list. Second you should stop using `malloc`, use `std::make_shared` or is absolutely necessary use `new`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code:

1. Syntax for member value initialization.

   This

   ```
   MyClass::MyClass() {
     this->data_((uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)), free);
   }
   ```

   is not how you initialize a member variable.

   ```
   MyClass::MyClass() : data_(value) {}
   ```

   is how you do it.
2. You need to use `new` to allocate memory when using `shared_ptr`, not `malloc`. In general, when using C++, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

<strike>3. There are too many arguments to `malloc`.</strike>

What you need to do for your particular class:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : data_(std::make_shared<uint8_t>()) {
}
```

**Update**

The point 3. above is not correct. I misread the arguments of `malloc` (Thanks @MikeSeymour). `free` is being passed to the constructor of `shared_ptr`, which is a valid way to construct a `shared_ptr`.

Even though

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> ptr(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)), free);
```

is a valid way to construct a `shared_ptr`, it's better to use

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> ptr(new sizeof(uint8_t)));
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> ptr(make_shared<uint8_t>());
```

Using `malloc` for `uint8_t` is potentially harmless since the value the `shared_ptr` points to can be set to something sane after the variable has been initialized. However, using `malloc` for anything a little more complex will require code that properly sets all the members of the object to sane values. If the object type has a virtual member function, I am not sure whether the `malloc` approach will work at all.

Comment: Better style to use `make_shared`, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza I wasn't able to test the use of `make_shared` on my computer. A newer version of g++ will probably work better. But I was able to test my suggested code.

Comment: OK, but `make_shared` is C++11, so it looks strange not to use it.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was able to test `make_shared`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Regarding point 2: you only need to use `new` if you use the default deleter (or a similar user-defined one), which uses `delete`. You can use `malloc` if, as here, your provide `free` (or something using `free`) as the deleter. (Whether or not you *should* use `malloc` is another matter, beyond the scope of this question). Regarding point 3: `malloc` is being called correctly with a single argument. Perhaps you misread the second `shared_ptr` constructor argument as a second `malloc` argument.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for the keen observation about the use of `malloc` and `free`. I added an update to my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was an error on my part. I admitted that i my update.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
MyClass::MyClass () : data_(new uint8_t) {
}
```

or (better)

```
MyClass::MyClass () : data_(std::make_shared<uint8_t>()) {
}
```

Concepts: [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new),
[make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

NB. This code snipped uses shared_ptr, but doesn't actually share anything. It is a waste to use shared_ptr for data that is not shared. In such cases use either std::unique_ptr or no pointer at all.

Comment: Better style to use `make_shared`, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, I'm still not used to it but it's the correct way.